# User and Project relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-models

So I have a User model created with devise and a Project model. A Project should have one Project owner and project members. So now I have no idea how to create the relations in my models.

What I have tried is have in my User model `has_many :projects` and in my Project model `belongs_to :user` but the problem with this is that the project is attached to only one User so i can't add any other users to it.

I tried changing it so that Project `has_many :users` but this causes my registration with devise to stop working since a user should belong to a project.

Something else I thought about doing is creating a class `ProjectOwner` and a class `ProjectMember` and then set that a Project `has_many :ProjectMember` and `has_one :ProjectOwner`. And set that a user `has_many :ProjectMember` and `has_many :ProjectOwner` since a User can be a project owner in many Projects and be a ProjectMember in others.

Or can I just set that a Project has an attribute of type User called ProjectOwner and another attribute of type User array that named ProjectMembers?

Since I'm pretty new to RoR, I'm not sure what is the right approach for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it looks like is you want a User, Role (with ProjectOwner and ProjectMember by STI), and Project

```
class  User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :projects, through: :roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project

  #Code that applies to both project owners and members
end

class ProjectOwner < Role
  #project owner specific code
end

class ProjectMember < Role
  #project member specific code
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_members
  has_many :members, class_name: "User", through: :project_members
  has_one  :project_owner
  has_many :owners, class_name: "User", through: :project_owner
end
```

Check out [this article](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) to help set up single table inheritance

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll give it a try. About the `id`, Role is gonna have one `user_id` and one `project_id`. Do I have to set a `user_id` and `project_id` for ProjectOwner and ProjectMember or not? And is Project going to have any `id` in its table?

Comment: so since `ProjectOwner` and `ProjectMember` both inherit from `Role`, they will actually use the `roles` table.  The `roles` table will have `user_id`, `project_id` and `type`.  The last one is critical since it is the column that designates what type of `Role` the row is.  The `User`, and `Project` will not have any foreign keys since the `Role` points to both of them.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'm getting a `Unknown key: :class` on `has_many :members, class: :User, through: :project_members`

Comment: right it is supposed to be class_name: fixing the answer

Comment: It's all working correctly, just one last question what is `type` going to be, Is it like a string Or is it gonna be of type Role which I can then assigne ProductOwner or ProductMember? And for the routes should i have the user routes seperated from Project or put the project routes inside the User routes?

Comment: `type` will be a string field on the `roles` data base that can either be set manually as `r.type = "ProjectOwner"`/`r.type = "ProjectMember"` or can be set automatically by doing `ProjectOwner.new`/`ProjectMember.new`.